# Destroy cookie when browser window closes PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have created a popup in WordPress that will open when visitor IP is from Australia. The popup will show up on page load. I want to make it not show until the browser screen is closed.

For this, I used the cookie. I set the cookie when the close button is clicked and creating the cookie in PHP using ajax.

Here is the code I am using to create cookie:

```
 setcookie("stay_here", "yes", 0, "/");
```

I set the cookie time to 0 so that it will destroy when the browser closed. The issue is that the site has user account area and when the user is logged in the session of the user is created. This session is not destroying after closing the browser. And when the above cookie created it automatically set expiration time as "Session".

I checked this on firefox and the data variable "Expires" of the cookie is set as "Session". As the session is not destroying when I close the browser and the cookie Expires value which is set as Session is also not destroying.

But I want the only cookie to be destroyed when the browser is closed not the Session.

I hope you understand my issue.

Can you guys look at the issue and provide me a solution to achieve this situation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally cookie created through SETCOOKIE function in PHP with its expire time 0, it will be deleted from browser when you will close the tab and time can't be overwrite with session's cookie time.

Try to create 1 test.php page and write setcookie("stay_here", "yes", 0, "/"); code and check from browser's cookie information.

You can also, set session cookie's time to 0 so session cookie will also deleted when browser will be closed.

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);

Comment: I tried this. In this case, cookie destroys as there is no session on the page. But I want that even if the session keeps alive, the cookie get destroyed after browser closed

Comment: Yes, even if your session cookie time is not 0 and you set cookie with 0 expire time your cookie will be expired on browser close but session cookie will be remain as it is. check accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way to destroy both session and cookie when browser close to fixing this issue?

Comment: set session cookie time to 0 by parameter session.cookie_lifetime or you can set it through .htaccess or from php.ini or from PHP file - ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);

Comment: will it affect my shopping cart too because the site is e-commerce site?

Comment: No it will not affect because session cookie will deleted if your browser is closed otherwise it will remain as it is.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are always Welcome !!

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

It states under "Session cookies":

> However, web browsers may use session restoring, which makes most
>   session cookies permanent, as if the browser was never closed.

In short: There is no reliable way to detect if a browser was closed.

What you can do is make a cookie that will expire in 12 hours:

```
setcookie("last_page_hit",$PHP_SELF,time()+12*60*60,"/");
```

if that cookie is absent you assume it is a new visit to the site and you show the popup again.

Comment: So, you mean I have to set expiry time instead of 0. Right?

Comment: Yes, that could make sense, but it is a rather crude approach. You could also store the last page hit in a cookie. If more than 12 hours have passed, since the previous page hit, you can assume it is a new visit. (sorry for the many edits of this comment)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your rm cookie is set and you are viewing page on header.php, you can refresh and update the cookie state.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['rm']) || (isset($rm) && $rm)) {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $lifetime);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $lifetime);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sessionStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
It will store on clients side until window is closed.
It's relatively new feature, so you should check if it's supported by your clients browsers.